# Modelling from 1 object or more?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I'm trying to learn how to use Blender, and thinking about making a model like the can in the photo. I'm thinking of starting it from a plane, extruding all over the model, and make it all from that.

**But my question is**: How can I make the round form of the tap, and make it morph into the box as in the picture.

[image]

Is this the right way of creating such a model? Or, is it better to use an extra cylinder for the tap, and the handle?

Comment: If you are quite new to Blender consider a comprehensive tutorial series.  It will be an efficient use of your time.  Here is one ..... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lY6KPrc4uMw&list=PLda3VoSoc_TR7X7wfblBGiRz-bvhKpGkS  .  You will have more questions after that education than you do now.

Comment: Thanks, but i am not totaly new, i know the basics, i dont expect any to tell me exact everything what to do to make a such model but since my way of learning is making a random item as a model in blender, and learn by doing. Lets ask like this instead...is my plan of building the model from vertices in one solid object the common way for such objects? or do the pro blender guys use multiple mesh objects even for this?

Comment: It is better to change your question  in the space provided for the original question.

Comment: By showing your work as an image we can tell your progress.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/14482/599

Answer (score 3):

**A Simplified Sample**

One mesh for the body of the container.  Cap not included.

[image]

Above in a progression of left to right, top to bottom

- Blue Cube Scaled
- Yellow  Loop Cuts
- Blue with faces deleted in the Handle area .. dark back faces
- Yellow [Bridge Edge Loops] so the handle with internal edges are present
- Blue Spout trough and crests with [Proportional Edit]
- Yellow with Subdivision Surface Modifier which smooths the corners in this example.
- For the round spout use [Extrude] and the add on ... Loop Tools.  That should be a different question.  Not shown in the above example.
- Extrude will be useful for decorative ridges.  Not shown.

The above has no detailed instructions since a Video Tutorial would be an efficient use of time for someone very new to Blender. This was mentioned in the comment. This proposed answer is not a tutorial. It can serve as a discardable practice model.  Blender Stack Exchange is not focused on artistry, but rather technique, question and answer.  I am sure you can be more artistic in your work than the simple model above.  Inspect and Improve the sample.

Click to see larger image above.

Comment: Thanks allot, well i just need little advices about what way to start, ofc this was maybe a question made wrong. I guess i need try more myself and rely on the result. Thanks allot for your help, it gave me some clues.

Answer (score 0):

It all comes down to personal preferences but I would start with a cube rather than a plane. In my opinion it makes things easier especially with the handle and the round part.

For the handle part I would extrude up the left and the right part and then connect them with aditional geometry.

The round part for the spout could be extruded the same way, but first I yould use the loop tools addon to create a rounded area.

Comment: Thanks for advices, yeah, maybe more easy to start from a cube, i will give it a try.