# Is it required to attach objects together as one?

Tags: modeling

I'm not done with youtube tutorials and I don't think they will mention it. Do you need to attach all parts together? for example the limbs to the body? I'm gonna use it to make a video game.

Comment: required not, often helps: it depends on your specific "video game" character needs... try to elaborate more on this.

Comment: I'm not sure I get it... In what situation does it help can you give an example? I'm sorry, I'm kind of making similar to nier automata but not that wide. Kind of like "narrow that game down significantly".

Comment: related: [What are the benefits of modeling in one piece, or as separate parts?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14482/what-are-the-benefits-of-modeling-in-one-piece-or-as-separate-parts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how far you are in designing the object, at the end you want to have as much objects attached to one another and the least amount of vertices so it'll be easier to handle for the engine.
At the beginning you can do as you want so you can edit certain parts better (for example if you have a t-pose it would be nice if you could move the arm away so you can edit the side of the body).

Comment: So it's ok to not attach the parts? Because, for example I want to attach something to something but the vertices don't match (let's not talk about subdividing it).

Comment: Your end model always had to be just on piece like a body, but before you have your endmodel you can just have it as loose parts. And you can always retopologize your model which is actually recommended if you have a model with alot of vertices.