# What are the pros/cons of having a model made of multiple meshes?

Tags: modeling, animation, mesh, topology

Here is a model shown in object and edit mode.  The topology is great, however, the body parts are all separate meshes.  From an animation perspective, what are the pros/cons of this approach, versus a single mesh?  Thanks!

Edit- mods believe my question has been answered here: [What are the benefits of modeling in one piece, or as separate parts?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14482/what-are-the-benefits-of-modeling-in-one-piece-or-as-separate-parts)

However, I think my question is sufficiently different as I'm asking about animation of an organic object, not hard surface modelling.

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14482/what-are-the-benefits-of-modeling-in-one-piece-or-as-separate-parts

Comment: If your object is a puppet, keep separate meshes. For a real human body, it needs to be one mesh, otherwise you would see the separations between the meshes.