# Best practice for creating complex models. Multiple meshes and textures?

Tags: modeling

Please forgive me if this is 'off topic,' the actual [**"What topics can I ask about here?"**](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page is void of any useful guidelines.

I'm new to Blender and started trying to make a model that is more complex than a simple object. Take any normal model, for example a car. Is it normal to make a car in one file that consists of a bunch of different non-connected meshes?

Most tutorials I have found make one giant connected object that is (in some way) connected to every part of the whole model.

My mind wants to separate the parts, like the wheels wouldn't be 'connected' to the body. I feel like this would make texturing and UV mapping easier, but nobody seems to do this. Texturing different parts of a single giant mesh is challenging for me and I wanted to know if it is bad practice to create lots of 'pieces' to a single model.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3305/when-is-acceptable-to-have-disconnected-geometry and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14482/what-are-the-benefits-of-modeling-in-one-piece-or-as-separate-parts

Comment: @cegaton Thanks for the reference. Would you create separate projects and import the finished texture/model as a whole or model the parts in a single project?

Comment: I would model individual parts in one project. The body shell might be one piece, but pieces like the wheels would be separate meshes. For a car you generally do not need to texture it, so that also influences my workflow.

Comment: @leigero a car would be made in *many* different pieces. The doors, bumpers, hood, front quarter panel, roof, wheels, tires, and so on, are all different pieces on a real car, and commonly separate on a 3D model.