# How do 3D modelers make their models?

Tags: modeling

I'm *very* new to the 3D modeling/CGI world and I'm just beginning to take my first steps to learning how to make my own models, scenes, etc. My question is how do modelers make their models? Do they model *every* little detail (clothes, jewelry, accessories, surface "deformities", etc.) on the model itself or do they construct separate models and piece them together like a puzzle onto the original model?

Any and all responses are greatly appreciated and thank you in advance! :)

Comment: Please try to make your question more focused. Strictly speaking it isn't about blender really, but 3d in general. If you are new to blender please start here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15355/resources-for-blender

Comment: Hello, welcome to BSE, this site is a Q&A community based website about Blender, please take the time to read the rules, your question is about modeling in general, this is not the right place to ask it, try Computer Graphics Stack Exchange: http://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Georges Computer Graphics is not the place for this question. This is a forum question that does not fit into SE.

Comment: If you want to learn to model well, I'd recommend just starting. You'd be amazed at how far you can get if you just make a point to make a few models. You'll learn from experience how much detail you can get away with and what the best ways to approach a model are.

Comment: I don't see that this question is necessarily off topic, as a matter of fact we even have a [similar question here](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/14482/599) which was well received. Also related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3305/599

Comment: @Joshua, I would recommend three things "practice, practice, practice". After that, evaluate what you have done, learn from your success and mainly from your errors. Also look often to the others realisations, learn from them. And, as a beginer, keep your first goals and realisations simple.

Comment: "How do people who do X do X?" is very broad.

Comment: @gandalf3 I think it was better received because, while the title is broad, they give a specific example.

Answer (score 0):

Well I am not a professional 3D modeler, but I do create models from scratch in Blender and here are a few ways I do it.

1. Using Metaballs and then converting it to a mesh

Normally this way is used to model a smooth and soft object, such as ribbons, sofas, slime monsters and pillows.

2. Modeling from a single object

Normally this is used for things that are simple and have flat faces, such as dice, balls and rocks

3. Creating a few meshes and joining them

In my opinion, this is the best way to model complex objects, such as people, cars and more. What's good about this method is you can export some of the parts like armour so you can use it in future projects.

This also means that a lot of people can work together to make a model at the same time by modeling each piece of the finished model. So I think this is the most possible method that modelers model models.

Answer (score -3):

If you model the pieces separately and want to join them, you have to make sure that they dont form any non manifold geometry AKA something that cant exist in real life like a face without any thickness or an edge without a face. Example:[What is non-manifold geometry?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7910/what-is-non-manifold-geometry)

Comment: This isn't relevant to the question, and it isn't true either. You can easily join together pieces when they aren't manifold. Sometimes that's the way to do it. It all comes down to what you're modeling and what gets you the result you want in the easiest way. Because in the end, what it looks like is all that really matter.

Comment: @TARDISMaker Unless of course you're printing it, in which case manifoldness > appearance