# What is a good topology?

Tags: modeling

This question might sound basic but I really can't find the answer to it. Here few examples. Should each mesh be connected together or be loose parts. I see sometimes in tutorials geometries that are floating and are not connected to other parts of the object, they simply go through a face without being connected to it. What should a clean topology be? Thanks.

[image]

Here some parts are floating.
[image]

Comment: IMO loose parts, especially for mechanical parts that don't deform.

Comment: It really depends on what you're going for.
For example if you end up wanting to 3D print your object it won't be possible because your mesh is not a solid.
If it's for in-game or fast rendering purposes you could easily let the parts float.
Do you want to render High resolution close-ups, then a solid model is preferable.
Could you elaborate your question a little more? What is the purpose of the model?

Comment: I was wondering what is the best workflow to obtain a clean model. I understand now that it depends on the final use. For example to render a realistic object with hard surfaces in high resolution, is it better to connect all the parts of the model? This is the case for all visual models used in  features? The first image shows that all the parts of the model are disconnected, they are like the layers of an onion. I understand it's better to build a model without floating parts for high reolsution but what about the connection between each part? Thanks.

Comment: Related- http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3305/when-is-acceptable-to-have-disconnected-geometry

Comment: If anyone answers, it would be nice if they could explain what topology is the best when using each process that @Delagone mentioned